# Cannot use | in springer's nature latex template

Tags: templates

Trying to write a single vertical bar in mathematical programming latex template  https://media.springernature.com/full/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/18782940/data/Download+the+journal+article+template+package

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\begin{document}

It thus suffices to prove that $ | $.  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using $\vert$ ?

Comment: Most often the vertical bar in equations is written `\mid', as in $\mid$.

Comment: I hope you found an answer. If not, here it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619280/springer-nature-2021-class-causes-error-when-writing-x?noredirect=1&lq=1